# Problems with Syntax and indentation errors

Tags: python

I'm going through a Book which, at this point in the book, requires me to make a small videogame that calls functions, uses `if`'s, `while`'s -- essentially all the things covered in the book so far. But, I get this error in this part of my code:

**Code edited, get a new error.**

> ```
>     File "ex35_study.py", line 24
> third_scenario_code()
> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
> ```

Here is my code:

```
     options_thirdscenario_actions = ['Examine the door', 'Try to force it']

def third_scenario_code():
    print "Let me try to crack this thing up, says Lars as he starts to type in the panel. You hear the sounds of the fight out there, there's not much time left. "
    print "After receiving several commands a window with a code pop ups. "
    print codefile.read() 


def third_scenario():
    print "You two get out of the cell and approach to the exit, a long corridor is ahead of you, flashing red lights indicate an state of emergency, you must evacuate."
    print "As soon as you two approach to the door, it closes"
    print "Crap it must be the emergency system, we have been detected"
    next = raw_input("What do you do> ")
if next == 'Examine the door':
    print "A small panel comes out, requires to enter a code of words"
    third_scenario_code()
elif next == 'Try to force it':
    print "You try to force the door with no result"
    print options_thirdscenario_actions    
    next2 = raw_input("What else do you do> " )
    if next2 = 'Examine the door'
        third_scenario_code()
else:
    print "You already did that"
```

I am getting a similar error on the whole program and I suspect it has something to do with indentation, but I have tried every suggestion I see in google with no fruitful result. thanks in advance.

Comment: `third_scenario_code()` should not be indented that much

Comment: As you can see, the `third_scenario_code`-lines are indented wrong. Never user tabs and always 4 spaces for indentation. Configure your editor to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing colons after the one of `if` conditions and need to line things that are the same scope up, i.e. the print after the function call but you may also be mixing spaces and tabs.  It is recommended to always use 4 spaces rather than tabs and most programming editors can be set up for this.

I would also suggest getting hold of [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) and using it.  It will help you spot a lot of potential errors and will help you to develop good habits.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the indentation of `third_scenario_code()` you need to write it under the `print` .

change the following :

```
if next == 'Examine the door':
            print "A small panel comes out, requires to enter a code of words"
                third_scenario_code()
```

to :

```
if next == 'Examine the door':
            print "A small panel comes out, requires to enter a code of words"
            third_scenario_code()
```

Comment: Did what you just mentioned, however I get a new error. I have only gotten these two types of error through the whole code, to be honest I have no idea on how to solve it.

Comment: @LittleFoot so now its because of mixing the spaces and tabs , try to use one of them for your code !

Comment: Thing is I am pressing the space key 4 times and I am still getting the error. I also modified Notepad ++ for spaces

Comment: @LittleFoot im sure that its the reason . any way if you think you have this error again write your code in a new file ! and run again!

Comment: Kesra, as much as I look into how indent documents I keep seeing that 4 spaces is the correct thing to do. Updated code. Could you please offer me an example using my code so I get an idea on what to do